# Getting error when apply auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UICollectionView` and a `UILabel` that I added `constraints` programmatically.

```
[_labelToChange setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_datesCollectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_labelToChange(30)]-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange, _datesCollectionView)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_labelToChange]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_labelToChange)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_datesCollectionView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_datesCollectionView)]];
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
2015-06-05 11:07:37.013 myApp[602:10299] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580420 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0(94)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580560 V:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580600 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c157ed80 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580420 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0(94)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-06-05 11:07:37.018 myApp[602:10299] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580560 V:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c1580600 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c15a95f0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f87c15a8840]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c15a9790 V:[UILabel:0x7f87c15a8840(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c15a98e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f87c15a8840]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f87c1959000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c15a9930 V:[UICollectionView:0x7f87c1959000]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7f87c157fda0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c157ed80 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f87c157f760(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f87c15a98e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f87c15a8840]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f87c1959000]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

What can I do to fix it?

**Update**

Thanks @rdelmar!! I did what @rdelmar said, and I now 1 error goes away but the other is still there:

```
2015-06-05 12:52:14.102 myApp[2373:44139] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1d80470 V:[DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1d80510 V:|-(0)-[DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9740 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9990 V:[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9a10 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00(85)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9a60 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':DIDatepicker:0x7fa2e1d7fd10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da4a50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa2e1d7f6d0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa2e1da9990 V:[UILabel:0x7fa2e1da8970]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fa2e20f8e00]>
```

Comment: You should remove the height constraint from DatePicker in your storyboard. That view already has constraints to the top and bottom of the cell. Adding a height constraint is over-constraining that view.

Comment: The problem I have is, it works in the project I sent you, but not in my main project. I checked what the difference between the 2 projects(regarding the datePickerView) and I didn't see any.

Would it be possible to have session via https://www.codementor.io . This way I can pay you for your work!
I was thinking of using teamViewer, but I then realized that I wouldn't be able to pay you. So the easiest way I think is through codeMentor. I really like working with you! that's why I'm not using others people on codeMentor.

Comment: Are you there? I want to know whether I should wait, or get someone else on codeMentor.

Comment: I'm not a mentor on codementor.io, so you should probably find someone else. I might look into signing up, but I don't know how long that takes.

Comment: Tomorrow night for what?